# Notepad++ Merge two lines

Tags: notepad++, regex

In Notepad++, how can I merge two lines in the stuation below?

```
RAW DATA    
26/11/15 26/11/15 1314  NEFT : CMS364134568 - CRE 
                        DIT CARD OPERATIONS       
26/11/15 26/11/15 1314  Cash Deposit              
27/11/15 27/11/15 1314  NEFT : CMS364860637 - CRE 
                        DIT CARD OPERATIONS       
27/11/15 27/11/15 1314  Cash Deposit              
30/11/15 30/11/15 1314  NEFT : CMS365476895 - CRE 
                        DIT CARD OPERATIONS       
30/11/15 30/11/15 1314  NEFT : CMS365573866 - CRE 
                        DIT CARD OPERATIONS       
30/11/15 30/11/15 1314  NEFT : CMS365623059 - CRE 
                        DIT CARD OPERATIONS

MERGED DATA                         
26/11/15 26/11/15 1314  NEFT : CMS364134568 - CREDIT CARD OPERATIONS       
26/11/15 26/11/15 1314  Cash Deposit              
27/11/15 27/11/15 1314  NEFT : CMS364860637 - CREDIT CARD OPERATIONS       
27/11/15 27/11/15 1314  Cash Deposit              
30/11/15 30/11/15 1314  NEFT : CMS365476895 - CREDIT CARD OPERATIONS       
30/11/15 30/11/15 1314  NEFT : CMS365573866 - CREDIT CARD OPERATIONS       
30/11/15 30/11/15 1314  NEFT : CMS365623059 - CREDIT CARD OPERATIONS
```

I tried several ways using Extended Mode and Regular Expressions , but cannot figure how to do the backspace part (get the DIT CARD OPERATIONS to Merge with CRE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I recognize the pattern well, you have:
space at the end of the line, then 24 spaces at the beginning of the next one, you need to remove them:

- open find and replace dialog
- check "regular expression"
- find what: `\n {24}`
- replace to: (nothing)
- replace all

you can check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/jViGi7/1)

---

> cannot figure how to do the backspace part

with regular expressions you don't insert backspace, just replace unnecessarily part to nothing.

### Update:

Working with Windows text files, you need to use `\r\n` instead of `\n`

Comment: Whats happening is, it's moving ` DIT CARD OPERATIONS` to the beginning of the same line it's on, but not merging it with `CRE`

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: +1 for the windows update!

Answer (score 0):

On:

26/11/15 26/11/15 1314  NEFT : CMS364134568 - CRE 
                        DIT CARD OPERATIONS

I used this expression as a filter:

(.+)(CRE)(.+)(\n)(.+)(DIT)(.+)

then applied:

$1$2$6$7

Result is:
26/11/15 26/11/15 1314  NEFT : CMS364134568 - CREDIT CARD OPERATIONS

Hope this help.

Comment: Why all these useless capture groups that slow down the process?